# UIColorPickerViewController color selection

Tags: ios, uikit, ios14, uicolorpickerviewcontroller

I have added the [UIColorPickerViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolorpickerviewcontroller) into my code like this:

```
@IBAction func colorPickerButtonTapped() {
    let colorPicker = UIColorPickerViewController()
    colorPicker.delegate = self
    present(colorPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func colorPickerViewControllerDidSelectColor(_ viewController: UIColorPickerViewController) {
    // view.backgroundColor = viewController.selectedColor
}

func colorPickerViewControllerDidFinish(_ viewController: UIColorPickerViewController) {
    // view.backgroundColor = viewController.selectedColor
}
```

Is there a way I can customize the colors that the user can select?

For example, if I want to allow my users to choose only gray-scale values, or only certain specific colors from my app color palette, is that possible with UIColorPickerViewController?

Comment: yes you can check with if viewController.selectedColor == gray color { allow to change  view.backgroundColor  }

Comment: Umm, I meant NOT giving the users that option in the first place to select those other colors. Maybe by customizing the UIColorwell or something...

Comment: no at present we unable to do this

Comment: Race to ask most popular questions started

Comment: After you get the selectedColor, you can adjust it if you have some logic that you would like to apply.  In my case I use the color to tint a semi transparent circular view to overlay onto other objects in an artistic drawing app.  I then immediately present to the user a separate slider which allows then to control the alpha (transparency) of the circular views color, effectively darkening or lightening it depending on the colors behind that circular view.  You could also adjust the RGB parts of the selected color if desired, with or without user input, snapping it to a closest gray value.